# Is it possible to bind one value from an Observable Collection?

Tags: c#, xaml, observablecollection

I have created the below class:

```
class WorkBook
{
    public string WorkSheetName { get; set; }
    public int TotalRows { get; set; }
    public string LastPopulatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

and have populated the following collection with 5 different 'WorkBook' objects:

```
    public ObservableCollection<WorkBook> WorkBookResults { get; set; }
```

In XAML, is it possible to perform a Linq statement to access one of these WorkBookData objects depending on what the worksheetname is?

I.e. A label will display the 'LastPopulatedDate' if the WorkSheetName = x and is in the WorkBookDataResults collection?

I do not need to change this value at the time, just display it.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Not cannot express this directly in XAML per-se, but with the help of an `IValueConverter` or `IMultiValueConverter` it should be rather easy to construct this conditional binding in XAML. However, i have two questions: What should the label display, if WorkSheetName is not in the WorkBookDataResults collection? And, what is this omnious **x** in `WorkSheetName == x`?

Comment: Oh, and a 3rd question :) What is the **WorkBookData** you mention?

Comment: IValueConverter is a cool solution, but also splitting the concern - so I'd suggest just make and expose in your data context (where `WorkBookResults` are) another property eg. `CurrentBookDate` - and inside perform the calculations, output empty string/date if none book applies - since it's a 'read only' that's relatively simple, no need to do PropertyChanged to sync and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change your observable collection to a dictionary:

`public Dictionary<string, WorkBook> WorkBookResults { get; set; }`

then you can do the binding as follows in xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=WorkBookResults[Sheet 1].LastPopulatedDate}"></TextBlock>
```

So, in the above xaml we are saying that we want to display the LastPopulatedDate value 
for "Sheet 1" worksheet.

The workbook results dictionary is populated as follows:

```
        WorkBookResults = new Dictionary<string, WorkBook>();

        var sheetName = "Sheet 1";
        var book = new WorkBook()
                        {
                            WorkSheetName = sheetName,Ad 
                            TotalRows = 10,
                            LastPopulatedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString()
                        };

        WorkBookResults[sheetName] = book;
```